# Tikz: Add Arrows (fro transformation) to two graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf

So far i have written the code for the graphs that i need. I'd like to have a nice arrow between the two graphs that should represent a kind of transformation. For example Graph 1 => Graph 2 (in the same "line").

[image]

[image]

The separate code of the two graphs:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % supersedes arrows
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 ->, >=Stealth, shorten >=1pt, % Stealth from arrows.meta instead of stealth'       
 from arrows
 thick,
 main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\Large\bfseries},
 every path/.style={>=latex},
 yellow box/.style={draw=black,fill=yellow, minimum size=4mm}
]

\node[main node] (a) {A};
\node[main node] (b) [below = 1.5cm  of a] {B};
\node[main node] (d) [below right = -0.5cm and 3cm of b] {D};
\node[main node] (e) [above = 1.5cm  of d] {E};

\node[main node] (g) [below right = 0.75cm and 2.5cm of e] {G};



\node[yellow box, below right = 0.75cm and 1cm of a] (i1)         
 {i\textsubscript{1}};

\node[yellow box, below right = 0.75cm and 1cm of b] (i2) 
 {i\textsubscript{2}};


\path (e) -- node[yellow box, midway] (i3) {i\textsubscript{3}} (g);

\path (d) -- node[yellow box, midway] (i4) {i\textsubscript{4}} (g);

\node[yellow box, above right=4mm and -2mm of i3] (i5) {i\textsubscript{5}};

\path
    (a) edge (i1)
    (b) edge (i1)
    (i1) edge (d)

    (b) edge (i2)
    (i2) edge (d)



    (e) edge (i3)
    (i3) edge (g)

    (d) edge (i4)
    (i4) edge (g)

    (g) edge[bend right]  (i5)
    (i5) edge[bend right] (e)


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

*code for the other graph*

\node[main node] (b) [below = 1.5cm  of a] {B};
\node[main node] (d) [right = 2cm of b] {D};
\node[main node] (e) [above = 1.5cm  of d] {E};

\node[main node] (g) [below right = 0.75cm and 2.5cm of e] {G};

\node[yellow box,  right = 0.75cm  of b] (i2) {i\textsubscript{2}};



\path (d) -- node[yellow box, midway] (i4) {i\textsubscript{4}} (g);

\path (g) -- node[yellow box, midway] (i5) {i\textsubscript{5}} (e);

\path

(b) edge (i2)
(i2) edge (d)

(d) edge (i4)
(i4) edge (g)

(g) edge (i5)
(i5) edge (e)
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason `name prefix` and `name suffix` seems to give strange results, so I added quotes by hand when distinguishing the node names in the left and right scope.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % supersedes arrows
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 ->, >=Stealth, shorten >=1pt, % Stealth from arrows.meta instead of stealth'       
 thick,
 main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\Large\bfseries},
 every path/.style={>=latex},
 yellow box/.style={draw=black,fill=yellow, minimum size=4mm}
]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=L]
\node[main node] (a) {A};
\node[main node] (b) [below = 1.5cm  of a] {B};
\node[main node] (d) [below right = -0.5cm and 3cm of b] {D};
\node[main node] (e) [above = 1.5cm  of d] {E};

\node[main node] (g) [below right = 0.75cm and 2.5cm of e] {G};



\node[yellow box, below right = 0.75cm and 1cm of a] (i1)         
 {i\textsubscript{1}};

\node[yellow box, below right = 0.75cm and 1cm of b] (i2) 
 {i\textsubscript{2}};


\path (e) -- node[yellow box, midway] (i3) {i\textsubscript{3}} (g);

\path (d) -- node[yellow box, midway] (i4) {i\textsubscript{4}} (g);

\node[yellow box, above right=4mm and -2mm of i3] (i5) {i\textsubscript{5}};

\path
    (a) edge (i1)
    (b) edge (i1)
    (i1) edge (d)
    (b) edge (i2)
    (i2) edge (d)
    (e) edge (i3)
    (i3) edge (g)
    (d) edge (i4)
    (i4) edge (g)
    (g) edge[bend right]  (i5)
    (i5) edge[bend right] (e);
\end{scope} 

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=R,xshift=9cm,yshift=-3cm]
\node[main node] (b')  {B};
\node[main node] (d') [right = 2cm of b'] {D};
\node[main node] (e') [above = 1.5cm  of d'] {E};

\node[main node] (g') [below right = 0.75cm and 2.5cm of e'] {G};

\node[yellow box,  right = 0.75cm  of b'] (i2') {i\textsubscript{2}};



\path (d') -- node[yellow box, midway] (i4') {i\textsubscript{4}} (g');

\path (g') -- node[yellow box, midway] (i5') {i\textsubscript{5}} (e');

\path
    (b') edge (i2')
    (i2') edge (d')
    (d') edge (i4')
    (i4') edge (g')
    (g') edge (i5')
    (i5') edge (e');
\end{scope}
\draw[double,double distance=1ex,thick,-{Implies[]},shorten >=1em,shorten <=1em]
     (L.east) -- (L-|R.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]